# Subtract hours and minutes from time

Tags: python, string, datetime, time

In my task what I need to do is to subtract some hours and minutes like (`0:20`,`1:10`...any value) from time (`2:34 PM`) and on the output side I need to display the time after subtraction.
time and `hh:mm` value are hardcoded

Ex:

```
my_time = 1:05 AM

duration = 0:50
```

so output should be `12:15 PM`

Output should be exact and in AM/PM Format and Applicable for all values
(`0:00 < Duration > 6:00`) .

I don't care about seconds, I only need the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=0, minutes=50)

d.strftime('%H:%M %p')
```

Comment: set datetime.today() to a variable and replace with d.replace(hour=1, minute=50) then subtract time

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me :

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '10:04:00'
s2 = '11:03:11' # for example
format = '%H:%M:%S'
time = datetime.strptime(s2, format) - datetime.strptime(s1, format)
print time
```

Comment: Would be nice if you'd explain your code a little bit.

Comment: Just pointing out that the result of the `print time` is `0:59:11`

Answer (score -11):

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("01:05:00.000", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
d2 = datetime.strptime("00:50:00.000", "%H:%M:%S.%f")

print (d1-d2)
```