# How can I subtract 3 hours from a datetime in a Pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns with datetime in gmt and I need subtract three hours from this datetime. For example in line 4 I need subtract startdate in 3 hours, the result it was: `08/02/2018 17:20:0`. And in the same line 4 I need to subtract enddate in 3 hours, the result it was: `08/02/2018 21:50:0`.

Initial table:

```
cpf  day  startdate              enddate
1234  1   08/01/2018 12:50:0     08/01/2018 15:30:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:30:0     08/01/2018 15:40:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 20:20:0     08/03/2018 00:50:0
1234  3   08/03/2018 01:00:0     08/03/2018 03:50:0
1235  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
5212  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
```

Result table:

```
cpf  day  startdate              enddate
1234  1   08/01/2018 09:50:0     08/01/2018 10:30:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 11:30:0     08/01/2018 10:40:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 10:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 17:20:0     08/02/2018 21:50:0
1234  3   08/02/2018 22:00:0     08/03/2018 00:50:0
1235  1   08/01/2018 08:50:0     08/01/2018 10:20:0
5212  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 10:20:0
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: pandas has a timedelta. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract hours and minutes from time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402022/subtract-hours-and-minutes-from-time)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `timedelta`

```
from datetime import timedelta

df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate']) - timedelta(hours=3)
df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate']) - timedelta(hours=3)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and subtract `3` hours timedelta:

```
cols = ['startdate','enddate']
td = pd.Timedelta(3, unit='h')
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') - td
```

If want aplly solution for each column separately:

```
td = pd.Timedelta(3, unit='h')
df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') - td
df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') - td
```

---

```
print (df)
    cpf  day           startdate             enddate
0  1234    1 2018-01-08 09:50:00 2018-01-08 12:30:00
1  1234    1 2018-01-08 11:30:00 2018-01-08 12:40:00
2  1234    1 2018-01-08 11:50:00 2018-01-08 12:50:00
3  1234    2 2018-02-08 17:20:00 2018-03-07 21:50:00
4  1234    3 2018-03-07 22:00:00 2018-03-08 00:50:00
5  1235    1 2018-01-08 08:50:00 2018-01-08 12:20:00
6  5212    1 2018-01-08 11:50:00 2018-01-08 12:20:00
```

Last if need convert datetimes to custom format:

```
df['startdate'] = df['startdate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['enddate'] = df['enddate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
    cpf  day            startdate              enddate
0  1234    1  08/01/2018 09:50:00  08/01/2018 12:30:00
1  1234    1  08/01/2018 11:30:00  08/01/2018 12:40:00
2  1234    1  08/01/2018 11:50:00  08/01/2018 12:50:00
3  1234    2  08/02/2018 17:20:00  07/03/2018 21:50:00
4  1234    3  07/03/2018 22:00:00  08/03/2018 00:50:00
5  1235    1  08/01/2018 08:50:00  08/01/2018 12:20:00
6  5212    1  08/01/2018 11:50:00  08/01/2018 12:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use timedelta

sample code

```
from datetime import timedelta 
delta = timedelta(hours=-3)
```