# Subtracting six hours from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My Pandas Dataframe has a column called `datetime`, which is the date for every specific row. I need to subtract six hours from every row of the `datetime` column. How can i do this?

Until now, i only managed to convert it to a new timezone, but not to subtract hours:

```
MyData['datetime'] = MyData['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris').dt.tz_convert('US/Central')
```

Comment: what have you tried to substrat the hours ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I subtract 3 hours of a datetime in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065104/how-can-i-subtract-3-hours-of-a-datetime-in-python). Just change 3 to 6.

Comment: `df['datetime'] - pd.Dateoffset(hours=6)` should do the trick