# How to subtract minutes from a python time object

Tags: python, python-datetime

If I have a python time object

```
import datetime
my_time = datetime.time(2,30,00)
```

What is the best way of subtracting ten minutes from "my_time"? Please note if time is 00:05:00 for example, expected result of this subtraction is 23:55:00.

I found a way to do it, but it feels like there's probably a better way. Also, I will prob have issues with timezone, using this way. Here it is:

```
import datetime 
my_time = datetime.time(2,30,00)
temp_date = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), my_time)
temp_date = temp_date - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
my_time = temp_date.time()
```

So essentially I first convert time back to datetime, do the operation I want, and then convert it back to time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract hours and minutes from time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402022/subtract-hours-and-minutes-from-time)

Comment: no, this question is specific about the python time object. I did find a way to do it, but it feels like there's a better way, hence I am asking ( will add the way I found to the question)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a `timedelta` object, which supports subtraction.

```py
from datetime import timedelta

time_1 = timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30, seconds=00)
time_2 = timedelta(hours=00, minutes=5, seconds=00)
delta = timedelta(minutes=10)

print(time_1 - delta)
print(time_2 - delta)

# Out
# 2:20:00
# -1 day, 23:55:00
```

Comment: feels better than converting to datetime. So, if you start with a time object, first you do timedelta(hours=my_time.hour, minutes=my_time.minutes, seconds=my_time.seconds), I guess. But then, because I need time again, I have to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764184/python-how-do-i-get-time-from-a-datetime-timedelta-object